# Is a 2-rank tensor written with respect to two bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I am an undergraduate physics student interested in math. I took an introductory linear algebra course last semester.

Consider 2-rank tensor $Q_{ij}$:

$$Q_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} 
Q_{11} & Q_{12} & Q_{13} \\
Q_{21} & Q_{22} & Q_{33} \\
Q_{31} & Q_{32} & Q_{33}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

To my understanding, this tensor is written with respect to a basis. For example, consider a tensor written in Cartesian coordinates:

$$Q_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} 
Q_{xx} & Q_{xy} & Q_{xz} \\
Q_{yx} & Q_{yy} & Q_{yz} \\
Q_{zx} & Q_{zy} & Q_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The double indices (e.g. $Q_{xx}$) give me the impression that this tensor is written w.r.t two bases. Additionally, the way this particular tensor transforms also suggests that you are transforming two bases (with a matrix and its transpose).

None of this thinking is rigorous, however. So, is a 2-rank tensor written with respect to two bases?

Comment: A tensor can be defined independently of any base. Actually, that is even the point of tensors. They are basis independent.

Comment: I was taught that tensors are multilinear objects that take in vectors and covectors and spit out scalars. Someone else also told me that tensors are defined by how they transform. Are these accurate, and is there a tensor definition that you would suggest? Is there a resource to see how to represent a tensor independent of bases including scalars and vectors? (Also, is your name from Crime and Punishment?) @Raskolnikov

Comment: Tensors are best defined as in your first definition. Your second one is the one physicists often use, but what it talks about is the way the coordinate representation of a tensor with respect to some choice of basis changes when you change basis. (Yes, my nickname is a Crime and Punishment reference).

Comment: @SillyGoose It isn't tensors that are defined by how they transform, it is "tensor fields" that are defined by how they transform. A tensor is, as you said, a multilinear map that takes in vectors and covectors and spits out scalars. A tensor field on an open set $U$ (or a manifold $U$) is a smooth map $A$ that assigns each point of $U$ a tensor (of the same type). The transformation law is what happens to the coordinate representation of a tensor when you change coordinates.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes:$$Q=\sum_{i,j}Q_{ij}e^i\otimes e^j\in V^*\otimes V^*$$Here $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: @Filippo Doesn't that make the answer no? There is a *single* basis here.

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed, I didn't understand the question. So the answer is no (I understand the accepted answer, but IMO this is how such matrices are usually interpreted). Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A doubly covariant tensor takes as input two (conventional) vectors, and spits out a scalar. The archetypal example of this is an inner product. If we want to put numbers on how this tensor behaves, the conventional thing is to fix a basis, and feed basis vectors in all possible combinations to the tensor and record the results.

*Usually*, you would use the same basis for both the input vectors, because it's nicer that way. But there is no formal reason you can't use two bases. It just gets messier than it has to.

Basically the same reasoning applies to mixed covariant-contravariant tensors (i.e. conventional square matrices from linear algebra), and for doubly covariant tensors: It is much more convenient to use the same basis / corresponding dual basis than to use separate, independent bases for the two ranks of the tensor, but it can certainly be done with two independent bases if you're careful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know of any applications for mixing bases?

Comment: @SillyGoose I personally know of no place where mixing bases makes things easier than picking a single good base.